# Strange error "sqlsrv_fetch_array(): 16 is not a valid ss_sqlsrv_stmt resource" since ReturnDatesAsStrings

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I am using the sqlsrv driver for IIS so I can connect to a MS SQL server in PHP.

I've managed to convert a lot of my original mysql_ code and all going well, until I tried to SELECT some DateTime fields from the database. They were coming back as Date objects in PHP rather than strings, I found the fix which is adding this to the connection array:

'ReturnDatesAsStrings'=>1

Since doing that though my code is broken when trying to populate my recordset:

```
    function row_read($recordset) {

    if (!$recordset) {
        die('<br><br>Invalid query :<br><br><bold>' . $this->sql . '</bold><br><br>' . sqlsrv_error());
    }

    $rs = sqlsrv_fetch_array($recordset);
    return $rs;
}
```

The error is: sqlsrv_fetch_array(): 16 is not a valid ss_sqlsrv_stmt resource

There is such little amount of help on that error in Google so this is my only shot! I just don't get it.

row_read is called from within a While: while ($row = $db->row_read($rs)) {

Any ideas?

Just to add more code and logic - I do a simple SELECT of all my orders, then as it loops through them, I do another 2 SELECT's on the orders table then the customer table. It's falling down when I try these extra 2 'gets':

```
        $this->db->sql = "SELECT * FROM TicketOrders";  

    $rs = $this->db->query($this->db->sql);

    $this->htmlList->path("skin/search.bookings");

    if ($this->db->row_count != 0) {
        while ($row = $this->db->row_read($rs)) {

            // Load the order row
            $this->TicketOrders->get($this->db, $row['Id']);                

            // Load the customer row
            $this->Customers->get($this->db, $row['CustomerId']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlsrv_fetch_array` need a ss_sqlsrv_stmt resource. There must be something wrong with your **SQL**.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but when I echo out 2 of my SQL statements then paste them back into SQL Studio they execute fine?

SELECT Id,CustomerId,NightId,ClubName,NightName,NightDate,Quantity,TicketType,Price,CancelledDate,OrderDate,QuoteNumber,Completed,Status,txn_id,EmailSent FROM TicketOrders WHERE Id= 1086730


SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress,Subscribe FROM Customers WHERE Id = 10068

Comment: @James Wilson: Maybe you can use `sqlsrv_errors()` to get the error detail.

Comment: Well isn't the detail: sqlsrv_fetch_array(): 16 is not a valid ss_sqlsrv_stmt resource???? I have tried echoing before and after that line and it is empty

Comment: @James Wilson: So where dose 16 comes from? I don't know the detail of your `get` method. But I guess `sqlsrv_query` return FALSE, and 16 may be the error code which can get form `sqlsrv_errors`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the 16 means - but I've stripped down my code loads and made it very simple - the problem seems to be looping through the array of the recordset. I have 92 records coming back in my first query, as I loop through, I can echo out data from the first row, when my code hits: $rs = sqlsrv_fetch_array($recordset ); on the second loop, I get that error. I have tried adding different fetchType's to that function with no luck. Could it be one of the other parameters I need? array sqlsrv_fetch_array ( resource $stmt [, int $fetchType [, int $row [, int $offset ]]] )

Comment: Holy crap well I've sussed it out! My sub queries were opening a connection as well (which has always worked on apache servers using mysql), but it was generating the error when using sqlsrv:

$db->connect();

Answer (score 4):

Did you pass this resource variable by another function? If yes, you can try by executing the `sqlsrv_query` and executing `sqlsrv_fetch_array` in one function; don’t pass the `ss_sqlsrv_stmt` resource by another function. Hope that it will help.

Comment: @wasimchy, why is it that $RecordSet cannot be passed by a function? Why would passing it by ref fail? And you are very right wasimchy, that it IS the cause of this problem.

Comment: My above entry ( which appears as an answer ) was supposed to be a comment! I could not figure it out; How do you add a comment to an existing comment?

Comment: It would be better if I could see your answer earlier. Probably, I traced into the problem so far in short time few weeks ago. Now, I remember so far it might be one limitation or bug of this new PHP driver for SQL server. I tested this same function (passing the resource variable as parameter) with other PHP driver and FreeTDS, there was no problem in both cases. It may return a different resource type ss_sqlsrv_stmt (if I don’t forget now) what can’t match with PHP resource type in my case. Because of time shortage, I just changed my functions style though somewhat less beauty of code.

Answer (score 2):

Does your program involves a nested query function?

If so, the next question is: are you opening the same database in the inner query function?

Try these changes:

1. comment out the lines that open the database, including the { and } that enclose the function,
2. change the name of connection and array variables between the outer loop and the inner loop.

In other words, the outer loop may have:

```
$tring = sqlsrv_query($myConn, $dbx_str1);    
while( $rs_row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($tring, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
```

and the inner loop would have:

```
$tring2 = sqlsrv_query($myConn, $dbx_str2);    
while( $rs_row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($tring2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
```